# Python: Markov switching model out of sample forecasts

Tags: python, forecasting, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, statsmodels

Is there a way to obtain out of sample forecasts for Markov switching models estimated via statsmodels (or any other package)?

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/markov_autoregression.html

The above page gives an explanation how to fit the models in-sample, but the results objects don't seem to have the forecasting method implemented.

```
res_hamilton.forecast(1)
```

Or

```
res_filardo.forecast(1)
```

both return *NotImplementedError*, the meaning of which I think is very obvious.

Did someone manage to find a way around this?
Any suggestions on how to do this manually are welcome as well.

Comment: The last question about "how to do this manually" looks like it might be on topic here on CV.  The preliminary questions about using statsmodels are not on topic.  Consequently, **any answer that only addresses the software will be converted to a comment** (or deleted).

Comment: I am running into the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `predict` method. According to the documentation, the `predict` method of the `MarkovAutoregression` class, performs "In-sample prediction and **out-of-sample forecasting**".

References:
[1](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression.MarkovAutoregression.html) [the `MarkovAutoregression` class documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression.MarkovAutoregression.html)
[2](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression.MarkovAutoregression.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression.MarkovAutoregression.predict) [the `predict` method of the `MarkovAutoregression` class documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression.MarkovAutoregression.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching.markov_autoregression.MarkovAutoregression.predict)